# HK2 MethodInterceptor with Jersey resource

Tags: java, jersey, aop, jersey-2.0, hk2

How can I set up an aop `MethodInterceptor` to work with Jersey resources?

Here is what I've tried, following [this](https://hk2.java.net/2.2.0/aop-example.html) documentation:

**Step 1 - InterceptionService**

```
public class MyInterceptionService implements InterceptionService
{
    private final Provider<AuthFilter> authFilterProvider;

    @Inject
    public HK2MethodInterceptionService(Provider<AuthFilter> authFilterProvider)
    {
        this.authFilterProvider = authFilterProvider;
    }

    /**
     * Match any class.
     */
    @Override
    public Filter getDescriptorFilter()
    {
        return BuilderHelper.allFilter();
    }

    /**
     * Intercept all Jersey resource methods for security.
     */
    @Override
    @Nullable
    public List<MethodInterceptor> getMethodInterceptors(final Method method)
    {
        // don't intercept methods with PermitAll
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(PermitAll.class))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return Collections.singletonList(new MethodInterceptor()
        {
            @Override
            public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable
            {
                if (!authFilterProvider.get().isAllowed(method))
                {
                    throw new ForbiddenException();
                }

                return methodInvocation.proceed();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * No constructor interception.
     */
    @Override
    @Nullable
    public List<ConstructorInterceptor> getConstructorInterceptors(Constructor<?> constructor)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Step 2 - Register the service**

```
public class MyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig
{
    public MyResourceConfig()
    {
        packages("package.with.my.resources");

        // UPDATE: answer is remove this line
        register(MyInterceptionService.class);

        register(new AbstractBinder()
        {
            @Override
            protected void configure()
            {
                bind(AuthFilter.class).to(AuthFilter.class).in(Singleton.class);

                // UPDATE: answer is add the following line
                // bind(MyInterceptionService.class).to(InterceptionService.class).in(Singleton.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However this doesn't appear to work because none of my resource methods are being intercepted. Could this be because I use `@ManagedAsync` with all of my resources? Any ideas?

Also, please do not suggest a `ContainerRequestFilter`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20556200/1415732) for why I can't use one to handle security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that rather than calling register(MyInterceptionService.class) you might want to instead add into your configure() statement:

```
bind(MyInterceptionService.class).to(InterceptionService.class).in(Singleton.class)
```

I am not sure it will work as I have not tried it myself so your results may vary lol

Comment: Oh good call! I had also tried doing this in configure(), but I did `bind(MyInterceptionService.class).in(Singleton.class)` which is definitely incorrect. Trying it now...

Comment: This works! Not sure if you've read my other question that I've linked above, but I now have an `AsyncContainerRequestFilter extends ContainerRequestFilter` in my project, and a generic way to register them, which I'm pretty excited about :)

Comment: For a more detailed example with GUICE + jersey have a look here https://github.com/mycom-int/jersey-guice-aop

Comment: Wow, what a gr8 page.  Would you mind if we pointed to it from the hk2 documentation on the guice/hk2 bridge?

Comment: Sure please feel free to do so.